# How can i combine multiple firestore query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can i combine multiple query for streambuilder I can only access the last one and how do I prevent it from refreshing the stream every time I return to the page

```
Stream<dynamic> _main;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _m = _firestore
        .collection(..)
        .where(..)
        .where(..)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => _onMUpdate(snapshot));
  }

void _onMUpdate(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        Stream<DocumentSnapshot> u = _firestore
            .collection(..)
            .document(doc.data['m'])
            .snapshots();
        Stream<QuerySnapshot> me = _firestore
            .collection(..)
            .document(doc.documentID)
            .collection(..)
            .limit(1)
            .snapshots();
        Stream<QuerySnapshot> n = _firestore
            .collection(..)
            .document(doc.documentID)
            .collection(..)
            .snapshots();
        _main =  StreamZip([u, me, n]).asBroadcastStream();
    });
  }
```

I want to thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you add details about your DB structure? It's not clear what you're trying to do, but these nested queries inside of loop don't look good at all.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, I think, it is optimal to use Observable.

1. You can create separate class BLoC.
2. Put there all Streams
3. Create there getter

> ```
> Observable<String> get merge => Observable.zip3(
>   _stream1,
>   _stream2,
>   _stream3,
>   (one, two, three) =>
>       (one.toString() + two.toString() + three.toString()));
> ```

And after that you can use this getter in your Streambuilder like this

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
            stream: counterBloc.merge,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(
                'Flutter Observable - ${snapshot.data.toString()}',
              );
            }),
```

I created example on the base of counter app. When button pressed it sends data to 3 streams and after display them.

The code example is here https://github.com/awaik/flutter_observable_example

It works like on image below.

Read more about zip3 here https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/zip3.html

Also instead of `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` you can use `BehaviorSubject<DocumentSnapshot>` it will keep last value of stream.

With such approach you will separate logic from UI and can reuse this streams anywhere in app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The StreamBuilder will update the layout based on the last snapshot, so it doesn't matter if you combine it, only the last one will update your screen.

I believe you can do something like this on your StreamBuilder:

```
// snapshotList will be your AsyncSnapshot. snapshotList.data will be your List<QuerySnapshot>

StreamBuilder<List<QuerySnapshot>>(
    stream: streamList,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshotList) {
        snapshotList.data.forEach((doc) {
            return something
        }
    }
)
```

Let me know if that works for you :)